# Python word count MapReduce errors on reading stdin

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to write a basic word count MapReduce in Python. Here is the mapper code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:

    try:
        # remove leading and trailing whitespace
        line = line.strip()
        # split the line into words
        words = line.split()
        # loop over words
        for word in words:
        # write out word and trivial count
            print '%s\t%s' % (word.strip(), 1)
    except:
        pass
```

I'm running on Ulysses from Project Guttenberg.

When I run it on my Hadoop cluster, I get this error message:

```
    File "<stdin>", line 1
    The Project Gutenberg EBook of Ulysses, by James Joyce
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't get what's wrong, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to run the book as Python file. Perhaps you are passing arguments in wrong order to something.

Comment: Yeah this was the issue. The execution string I was using was wrong, so Python was attempting to read the input as a script. I had to surround the mapper in quotes, e.g. -mapper "python mapper.py".

Answer (score 0):

Oh, are you running Python 3?

Python 3 changed the syntax for `print`, which needs to be `print(...)`

Also, you could use `.format()` like so:

**POSSIBLE ANSWER**

`print('{word}\t{value}'.format(word=word.strip(), value=1))`

Can be simplified to: `print('{}\t{}'.format(word.strip(), 1))`

*ALSO*
If you have a "line" such as "The Project Gutenberg EBook of Ulysses, by James Joyce"

You will probably also want to strip out `,`'s ;)